# How to import cookies to safari browser

Tags: safari, cookies, import

I want to import cookies to safari browser from google browser which I've exported them using the cookie-editor plugin. Is there a way to do the same here.

Comment: Does [Export bookmarks from Chrome to Safari | Macworld](https://www.macworld.com/article/671456/how-to-export-bookmarks-from-chrome-to-safari.html) answer your question?

Comment: no because I want to import cookies from a site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cookie-Editor extension that you mention in your question now fully supports Safari on Mac OS and iOS. You can use it to import/export your cookies the same way you would on other browsers.

Here are two links where you can find details about Cookie-Editor:

- For Safari: https://apps.apple.com/app/apple-store/id6446215341
- For other browsers/general info: https://cookie-editor.cgagnier.ca/

Comment: Upvoted the answer :-)